# Why Spring Boot Gradle Project Build failed with an gradle-plugin exception?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I have the **spring boot version '1.4.3.RELEASE'** project. It was developed with **Java 1.8** and used **gradle-4.5.1**. When I was going to build it I faced this error,

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'rezg-hotel-setup'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.3.RELEASE.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.3.RELEASE.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-1.4.3.RELEASE.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-1.4.3.RELEASE.pom'.
               > Received fatal alert: protocol_version

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

**build.gradle file**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties file**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.5.1-bin.zip
```

**What are the best possible options?**

Comment: This is likely due to the fact that many servers have stopped supporting older, less secure versions of the HTTPS protocol, and it appears that the version of Gradle you're using (4.5.1) is attempting to use one of these older versions.

Comment: Can not reproduce the issue with your setup. Maybe related to different jdk 1.8 version. As suggested in the log, try --stacktrace and --debug to get more information first.